# Die roll until we get 5 and 6, no matter in what order. Find expected value and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, variance

I am not sure of my result.

First we define $X$ and $X=k+1$ when in $k+1$-throw we obtain 5 or 6 for the first time. Then $P(X=k+1)=(4/6)^k(2/6)$ and $\mathbf{E}X=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)P(X=k+1)=3$
So now we have 5 or 6 and we need to wait for the other number. So we start "from the beginning" but now we wait for one specific number, so expected value is $\mathbf{E}Y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)P(Y=k+1)=6$ where $P(Y=k+1)=(5/6)^k(1/6)$. So our expected amount of throws is $9$.

Before looking for variance I'd like to confirm that result.

Comment: The expected amount of throws to get just a 6 would be....6. Because there are 6 sides and each side has same probability. Now if I keep throwing until I get a 5 or 6, shouldn't that expectation go down? After all, I can "mimick" this experiment with a three sides die, waiting for one particular side to "emerge"...

Comment: @imranfat you keep throwing until you get 5 and 6, not 5 or 6.

Comment: Yes, that is right. This is related to the "coupon-collector's" problem.

Comment: Ah...ok, you throw a 5 or 6, record it and then keep throwing until the other "missing" number comes up?

Comment: @imranfat That's right.

Comment: @LordShark So now to have variance I need to find expected value of $(X+Y)^2$? to do $\mathbf{E}(X+Y)^2-(\mathbf{E}(X+Y))^2$?

Comment: The variables are independent; the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances.